# How to separate multiple answers in one column, for multiple columns, by creating extra columns

Tags: r, string, csv

## 1.Data

I have survey data:

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(4, 5), Start_time = structure(c(1676454186, 
1676454173), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    End_time = structure(c(1676454352, 1676454642), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `want_to_change Mult answ` = c("Yes (for the environment), because it provided a starting point to collectively do something about energy consumption.;", 
    "Yes (because of the gas crisis), because it provided a starting point to collectively do something. ;"
    ), actually_changed = c("Yes, I tried to use less energy in the office.", 
    "No, not at all."), `control Mult answ` = c("We / I can control the lights.;Closing/opening doors and windows.;", 
    "We / I can control the lights.;Closing/opening doors and windows.;"), `measures_taken Mult answ` = c("Yes, I checked for lights that were not turned off.; Yes, went home early", 
    "Yes, I checked for lights that were not turned off.;")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

that looks as follows:

[image]

## 2. Structure of the data

Some of the columns can have more than one answer. These columns have `"Mult answ"` in the column name. See for example row 1, column 6 (`dat[1,6]`).

```
> dat[1,6]
                                                    control Mult answ
1: We / I can control the lights.;Closing/opening doors and windows.;
```

## 3.Question

I would like to write a piece of code that:

1. Changes all answers that only occur once to `Other` (this is because there are many custom answers).
2. Creates a separate column for each answer option, with a generic suffix.

## 4. What I have tried

I thought I would first select the columns that have multiple answers:

```
# Get columns with more than one answer
temp <- select(dat,contains("Mult answ"))
cols_with_more_answers <- names(temp)
```

I then thought to split the columns up by the semicolon (before I count them and change the unique ones to `other`). But I have multiple columns and NEVER know how many answers there might be..

```
# Separate columns 
tidyr::separate(data.frame(text = dat), text, into = c("A", "B", "C"), sep = ";", fill = "right", extra = "drop")
```

How should I continue here?

## 5. Desired output

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(4, 5), 
                       Start_time = structure(c(1676454186, 1676454173), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                       End_time = structure(c(1676454352, 1676454642), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                       `want_to_change Mult answ` = c("Other", "Other"), 
                       actually_changed = c("No, not at all.", "Yes, I tried to use less energy in the office."), 
                       `control Mult answ A` = c("We / I can control the lights.", "We / I can control the lights."), 
                       `control Mult answ B` = c("Closing/opening doors and windows", "Closing/opening doors and windows"), 
                       `measures_taken Mult answ A` = c("Yes, I checked for lights that were not turned off.", "Yes, I checked for lights that were not turned off."), 
                       `measures_taken Mult answ B` = c(NA, "Yes, went home early")), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
                  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.
(converting questions to letters and make it stable in case you had more than 26 answers was a bit tricky but I found a way around it)

I left a few comments into the code, in short:

- Pivot multiple answers questions into rows and separate the answers with `separate_rows`.
- At that point you can replace the answers that appear only once with `forcats::fct_lump_min`.
- Then you can create a new columns to convert answers to letters (for that I had to create the function `values2letters` that calls `expand_letters`. The first function simply recode the answers into letters. The second function create the letters. If you have more than 26 answers, letters wouldn't be enought so the function makes combinations of letters).
- In the end, you spread the answers over the combination its own question and corresponding letter to get the expected result.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


expand_letters <- function(l){
  
  # how many times letters must repeat?
  x <- ceiling(log(l, 26))
  
  # correct in case of zero
  x <- max(x,1)

  # repeat the letters
  x <- rep(list(LETTERS), x)
  
  # get combinations
  x <- expand.grid(x)
  
  # collapse letters
  x <- do.call(paste0, rev(x))
  
  # return only the needed ones
  x[seq_len(l)]
  
}

values2letters <- function(x){
  
  x <- factor(x)
  levels <- levels(x)
  l <- length(levels)
  new_levels <- expand_letters(l)
  recode <- setNames(levels, new_levels)
  as.character(forcats::fct_recode(x, !!!recode))
  
}

dat %>%
  
  # pivot only multi answers
  pivot_longer(ends_with("Mult answ")) %>% 
  
  # separate by ; in multiple lines
  separate_rows(value, sep = ";") %>% 
  
  # remove empty rows (automatically created at the end beacuse lines ends with ;)
  filter(value != "") %>% 

  # change to Other if appears less than 2
  mutate(value = as.character(forcats::fct_lump_min(value, 2))) %>%
  
  # recode to letters by question
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(valueLetters = values2letters(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  # distinct in case you have multiple "Other"
  distinct() %>%

  # spread values
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, valueLetters), values_from = value, names_sep = " ")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 9
#>      ID Start_time          End_time            actual~1 want_~2 contr~3 contr~4
#>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1     4 2023-02-15 09:43:06 2023-02-15 09:45:52 Yes, I ~ Other   We / I~ Closin~
#> 2     5 2023-02-15 09:42:53 2023-02-15 09:50:42 No, not~ Other   We / I~ Closin~
#> # ... with 2 more variables: `measures_taken Mult answ B` <chr>,
#> #   `measures_taken Mult answ A` <chr>, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   1: actually_changed, 2: `want_to_change Mult answ A`,
#> #   3: `control Mult answ B`, 4: `control Mult answ A`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>